# Reporting system for multi-tenant, multi-lingual system

Tags: reporting-services, multilingual, multi-tenant

This is quite a heavy list of requirements, but I wonder if anyone here has any ideas I can investigate for this.

We require a reporting system to support a multi-tenant, multilingual database system.  The system will be available via the internet – it is not intranet based.  We will be using SQL Server 2008 R2 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

In the system, each tenant will have their own database.

Each tenant can set their own captions for the fields in each table in the system.  Any caption changes must be reflected in the reports.

The tenants must be able to edit existing reports or create new reports.

When doing so, the tenant must not be able to view or edit any other tenant’s reports.

A tenant must not be able to create a report which can view another tenant’s data.

A user may be restricted in which fields in a table he can view – the user must not be able to create a report to view these restricted fields.  Different users or groups of users will have different restrictions on which fields or tables they can view.

The reporting system must be capable of providing different types of reports e.g. graphs, tabular data, reports by calendar/academic/financial year, form style reports.

Can SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 meet all of the above requirements?

If so, how do we set up Reporting Services to meet these requirements?

Alternatively, is there another reporting tool which can meet these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have just completed a new revision of the beta build of our new [ActiveReports Server](http://www.activereportsserver.com/) product that includes multi-tenant support for exactly the types of scenarios you describe.
Since we just published the feature this week we don't have ideal documentation yet but you can see the basic documentation [here](http://www.activereportsserver.com/Documentation/AdministratorGuide/index.html?ManagingSecurityFilters.html).

It includes a web browser-based drag & drop ad hoc report designer powered by automatically generated and fully customizable logical data models that protect business users from underlying technical details.

You can deploy one model to each tenant or you can use a placeholder in the connectionstring to use one model for multiple tenants.

I think we can cover all of the requirements that you mention above. If there is something missing let me know and I'll see if it will fit into our roadmap.

```
Scott Willeke
Product Manager | ActiveReports Server
GrapeCity inc.
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  The team will have a look at ActiveReports Server.